# References about the Heat equation approach to Chern Gauss Bonet Theorem

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

I am looking for a concise self contained proof of the Chern Gauss Bonnet Theorem with the heat equation approach. I am currently studying The Laplacian on a Riemannian Manifold: An introduction to analysis on manifolds by Rosenberg. There are some exercises used in the proof of the theorem that I am not able to solve so I am looking for references to these exercises or even better a complete proof of the theorem with some more details. I tried reading the original papers by Singer, Patodi but they are a bit too hard for me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I suggest that you keep hammering away at the problems and perhaps ask questions here about specific steps that you're not sure about. Figuring out the proof yourself is way way more valuable than reading someone else's proof.

Comment: Perhaps Peter Gilkey's book(s) on the heat equation, Atiyah-Singer, and Gauss-Bonnet might help.